# Express.js, mysql, separating data items by one attribute

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, express, javascript-objects

I have a variable called **row** that contains this:

```
[ RowDataPacket {
    id: 15,
    worknumber: '543/242',
    note: '',
    timestamp: 2018-12-18T12:17:15.000Z,
    uploadroute: null,
    isDone: 'false' },
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 16,
    worknumber: '123/123',
    note: 'retek',
    timestamp: 2018-12-18T12:17:15.000Z,
    uploadroute: null,
    isDone: 'false' },
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 17,
    worknumber: '5/34',
    note: 'anal',
    timestamp: 2018-12-18T12:17:15.000Z,
    uploadroute: null,
    isDone: 'false' } ]
```

I would like to separate this content into two other variable, depending on this "isDone" attribute.
Here is the code for the call I made:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var totalTrue;
    var totalFalse;
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM tickets", function (err, row, field) {
        for (i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
            if (row[i].isDone == "false") {
                totalFalse += row[i];
                console.log(totalFalse);
            } else {
                totalTrue += row[i];
            }
        }
        res.render('list', { title: 'List', layout: 'listLayout', trueRow: totalTrue, falseRow: totalFalse });
    })
});
```

For some reason the "totalFalse" variable will contain this after the call:

```
undefined[object Object][object Object][object Object]
```

I don't know how to separate the "RowDataPocket"s into these variables correctly while they keeping their structure. Please share a solution with me, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be treating arrays and objects as if they were strings. You can't concatenate an object to another one like that and expect sensible output - it just stringifies them, which is useless.

Here's what I think you intended - have two empty arrays, and then push items from the response into one or other of these arrays depending on the isDone status of the item:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var totalTrue = []; //defined as an array
    var totalFalse = []; //defined as an array
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM tickets", function (err, row, field) {
        for (i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
            if (row[i].isDone == "false") {
                totalFalse.push(row[i]); //add a new item to the array
                console.log(totalFalse);
            } else {
                totalTrue.push(row[i]); //add a new item to the array
            }
        }
        res.render('list', { title: 'List', layout: 'listLayout', trueRow: totalTrue, falseRow: totalFalse });
    })
});
```

---

P.S. I don't know if what you're intending to send to the "render" method is the actual data itself in each array, or just a count of how many items were in each category? If you just want to keep a count, then you could dispense with the arrays and just do this:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var totalTrue = 0; //counter
    var totalFalse = 0; //defined as an array
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM tickets", function (err, row, field) {
        for (i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
            if (row[i].isDone == "false") {
                totalFalse++; //increase the count
                console.log(totalFalse);
            } else {
                totalTrue++; //increase the count
            }
        }
        res.render('list', { title: 'List', layout: 'listLayout', trueRow: totalTrue, falseRow: totalFalse });
    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, actually I was looking for the way how to push items into the arrays and you showed that well, thank you!